# JS Constructor is outputting undefined value

Tags: javascript, class, oop

The purpose is to make a countdown timer, but I keep getting an undefined value of 'sec'. There's might be a 'bind' is missed somewhere (100% per cent I have include inaccurate context somewhere), but I can not find a proper mistake right now. Would be really grateful if someone could help with resolving of the issue.

Attaching HTML as well.

```
class CountdownTimer {
  constructor(selector, targetDate) {
    this.timer = document.querySelector(selector);
    this.targetDate = targetDate;
    this.refs = {
      day: this.timer.querySelector("span[data-value='days']"),
      hour: this.timer.querySelector("span[data-value='hours']"),
      min: this.timer.querySelector("span[data-value='mins']"),
      sec: this.timer.querySelector("span[data-value='secs']"),
    };
  }
  updateClockItems(time) {
    const pad = this.pad;

    const days = pad(Math.floor(time / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
    const hours = pad(
      Math.floor((time % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60))
    );
    const mins = pad(Math.floor((time % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)));
    const secs = pad(Math.floor((time % (1000 * 60)) / 1000));

    this.refs.day.textContent = `${days}`;
    this.refs.hour.textContent = `${hours}`;
    this.refs.min.textContent = `${mins}`;
    this.refs.sec.textContent = `${secs}`;
  }

  pad(value) {
    return String(value).padStart(2, "0");
  }
  loadingTimer = setInterval(() => {
    const startTime = Date.now();
    let diff = this.targetDate - startTime;
    this.updateClockItems(diff);
  }, this.refs.sec);
}

new CountdownTimer({
    selector: '#timer-1',
    targetDate: new Date('Jul 17, 2021'),
});



HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>11th HW</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="timer" id="timer-1">
      <div class="field">
        <span class="value" data-value="days">00</span>
        <span class="label">Days</span>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <span class="value" data-value="hours">00</span>
        <span class="label">Hours</span>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <span class="value" data-value="mins">00</span>
        <span class="label">Minutes</span>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <span class="value" data-value="secs">00</span>
        <span class="label">Seconds</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: The code doesn't work at all, you're passing a single object to the constructor, but then trying to read values from two separate arguments. Define only a single argument in the argument list of the constructor (ex. `options`), and read properties of that object. Also, the interval is defined before `refs` exists, move the property definition to the constructor after the lines defining `refs` (class property fields are also not widely supported yet). After these changes your [code should work](https://jsfiddle.net/3spbjdw9/).

Comment: thanks a lot!!! but I don't quite understand " the interval is defined before refs exists" - what do you mean?

Comment: When you define `loadingTimer` within the class, it uses `this.refs.sec` as the delay, but `this.refs` doesn't exist at the time the class is defined.

Comment: @Teemu , sorry for a stupid question, I am a total beginner - how can I check if something exists at this time or no?

Comment: Mostly you can see the execution order by just looking the code. If there's a doubt, you can always use DevTools, set break points to the code, and read the value/reference when the code breaks, or log it to the console. You can also just run the code, and read the error message(s) from the console.